# Android Option "Nothing to Show" but File option alright

Tags: android, flutter

In my existing flutter application when I open it with Android Studio (Version 4), it's building and running with no problem. But when I click the android option, it shows "Nothing to show".

[image: Error in Android Option]

Again when I click file option then it shows no errors.

[image: File Option Alright]

**How can see a file in Android option?**

Answer (score 1):

Android option is only for Android projects, not Flutter projects.
If you try to open android subfolder of your Flutter project with android studio you can use android option.

Comment: Yes. I have both ios and android options. But not show android option.

Comment: As I told, it tells you "nothing to show" because your project is not an android project, it is a Flutter project.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.